# Async Function wrapped in jQuery Selector, Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, async-await

Aspiring newbie, hope this isn't too general of a question...

I was given some javascript where the entire file starts by wrapping everything in an asynchronous function that is inside of a jQuery selector. The file structure is included below.

```
$(async function() {
  const $jQObject = $('#class')

  $jQObject.on("submit", async function(){
  ...code
  })
  
  async function func1 (){
  ...code
  }
  
  function func2 () {
  ...code
  }
})
```

I was wondering,

1. I don't see a purpose of the initial jQuery selector that wraps everything.
2. Why wrap async functions with an anonymous async function...?

Comment: 1) is a shortcut for running the function inside after the document has loaded 2) allows you to use `await` outside an inner async function

Comment: Thank you! @ChrisG